# Is there an Enable Frame Blending option or replacement in Blender 2.76a?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, properties

Frame blending is a very useful function to have when messing about with frame rates and timings of movies and frame sequences.  It's clear that that option is no longer available (at least, overtly) in 2.76a.  Is there a hidden switch, or is it built into some of the options in VSE's Speed Control effects strip?

Comment: maybe you can find the answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28226/how-to-enable-frame-blending-in-blender-2-74